# Regexp for valid ending

Tags: java, regex

I can't come up with a regexp for my purposes. I am trying hard with something close to this

`(?!\{%)\s*endfor\s*%}`

but it's not working as I would like.

It should find invalid uses like:

`- % endfor %}
-         % endfor %}
- { % endfor %}
- endfor %}
- {% something valid %} % endfor %}`

but should not find valid uses like:

`- {% endif %}
- {%      endif   %}
- {%endif%}
// multiline
- {%
- endif
- %}`

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want this pattern to do, and how your current pattern fails. From your examples, it just looks like you want to trap anything with `"endfor"` in it.

Comment: Why not find valid cases using `\{%\s*endif\s*%}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use the negative in your match so instead to detect the wrong case with your regex, you can use `!match` instead for example :

```
if(!str.matches("\\{\\%\\s*endfor\\s*\\%\\}")){
//-^-------------------------------------------------
  //do this
}
```